# Public variable in Recursive function C#

Tags: c#, recursion, treeview, global-variables, treenode

I have a function that is recursive in C# that i want to edit a global variable(i assume it is global due to the public before it) declared outside the function. For some reason that i do not know it cannot see the public variable within that specific function. It can see it in the first function in my code, but not in the second where i need to access it and change it to save a LOT of time opening a LOT of files...

Is there any reason why it wouldnt be accessable? and if so, how can i either get around it?

Thanks so much in advance!

```
public int[] timeInfo = new int[2];
   private void ListDirectory(TreeView treeView, string path) 
        {     
            treeView.Nodes.Clear();   
            var rootDirectoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);    
            treeView.Nodes.Add(CreateDirectoryNode(rootDirectoryInfo)); 
        }

   private static TreeNode CreateDirectoryNode(DirectoryInfo directoryInfo) 

   {

       var directoryNode = new TreeNode(directoryInfo.Name);

       foreach (var directory in directoryInfo.GetDirectories())
            directoryNode.Nodes.Add(CreateDirectoryNode(directory));

       foreach (var file in directoryInfo.GetFiles())            
       {

           int check =0;                         
           try                
           {

               string s = "";                    
               s = directoryInfo.FullName + "\\" + file.Name;                    
               List<string> row, row2, row3 = new List<string>();

               using (StreamReader readFile = new StreamReader(s))
               {

                   row = (readFile.ReadLine().Split(',').ToList());
                   try 
                   {                           
                       row2 = (readFile.ReadLine().Split(',').ToList());
                       //timeInfo[0] = row2[0];
                   }
                   catch { check = 1; }
                   try
                   {
                       row3 = (readFile.ReadLine().Split(',').ToList());
                       //timeInfo[1] = row3[0];
                   }

                   catch { }
                }

                TreeNode[] headerNodes = new TreeNode[row.Count];

                for (int i = 0; i < row.Count; i++)
                {

                    headerNodes[i] = new TreeNode(row[i]);
                    if (check == 1)
                    {                       
                        headerNodes[i].BackColor = Color.Red;
                        headerNodes[i].ForeColor = Color.White;
                    }

                }
                directoryNode.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(file.Name, headerNodes));
            }
            catch 
            {
                directoryNode.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(file.Name));
            }
        }         
        return directoryNode; 
    }
```

Comment: what exactly are you going to do with `timeInfo[]` as each recursive call will overwrite the values

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second function is static, and the variable exists only in the context of an object.

Comment: Don't... we've all been there.

Answer (score 5):

The method is static.  The variable is not.  You cannot access non-static (instance) members of the class from within a static method.  A public variable in a class is not global.  You must make it public static to make it global (not that I would ever recommend using global variables), such as:

```
public static int[] timeInfo = new int[2];
```

Answer (score 3):

You would need to make it static in order for your static function to see it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define your variable as static as well:

```
public static int[] timeInfo = new int[2];
```

Answer (score 1):

Your variable must be static because of your method. Because the method is static, it can only see static variables.